# Binding in C++ like in C#

Tags: c#, c++, binding

Is it possible to bind variables in C++ like in C#(converting values ... auto updating ... etc)??

I had a short experience with C++ a few years ago and have been programming in  C# for about a year and a half now. Now I want to go back to C++ and that question came to mind. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're after.. in C# though?

Comment: I think he might mean [WPF data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)...

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no data binding in C++ like C#. However, it is entirely possible to implement this functionality by deriving classes from MFC classes, creating your own classes, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct IDE-level schema for C++ to bind a model to a view. Languages like C# and Obj-C were designed with this in mind, as were the frameworks built around them. So even though you can't use an interface builder to bind your model to view, maybe code a little boilerplate code and BAM application works... you can still get the same effect but you'll need to understand the boilerplate code behind this pattern more directly.

Qt is a fine example as always:
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/model-view-programming.html